# Saving scores online in android

Tags: android, database

I am making a game in android, and I would like to save global scores.

Not global on one device only but **worldwide** global scores.

Do I have to make server for this or there are some free `databases` for this purpose? Or maybe there's another simple solution?

Comment: You're on your own basically.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).
It provides a real-time database that can store your data. 
It's also simple to use and well documented.

And it's free until you reach the limit of storage.